# Sql Server Plan - what is a Filter after an Index operation?

Tags: sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I've encountered this condition while optimising a SP, there's a part of the execution plan I really don't get: SQL Server does an **Index scan**, then it filter the results. What are the reason for SQL Server to do so, instead of doing all in the **Index scan**?

For an example:

[image]

The index already contains all the fields used by the **WHERE**. I expanded the **Index Scan** operation, and it execute part of the where with some parameters involved (totally expected). I then expanded and inspected the **Filter** operation, and what it does is to apply some other filtering on a couple datetime fields already evaluated by the **Index Scan**, plus some other conditions on some other SP parameters.

What's going on here? I obviously don't care about my specific query, that's not the point, I'm trying to understand what conditions can cause this to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter operators are often used for non-SARGable predicates, or when the predicates are too complicated to be pushed effectively to the index access operation.

In your case, I'm willing to bet that it's a series of optional predicates. These are not SARGable: [Conor vs. Optional Parameters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/22/conor-vs-optional-parameters/) .

> ...plus some other conditions on some other SP parameters...

If your code is doing something like `col = @var or @var IS NULL`, it would fall into that category, and may result in the filter operator.